# jquery , asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am trying to use jquery to select a checkbox when another checkbox is selected. This wuld have been easy if the ids of the checkboxes are constant but they can change so I have tried to use classes instead, unfortunately asp.net applies the class name on the span element wrapping the checkbox instead of applying on the checkbox directly, so i need to get the checkbox via the inner element of the parent span

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Category_ctl00_ProductBusinessLine_chkEL_157').click(function() {

     if (this.checked) {
         var pl = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Category_ctl00_ProductBusinessLine_chkPL_313')


         pl.attr("checked", true);
     } 


         })
     }); 
</script>
```

My code, previously working with the checkbox ids, is above, pls help!

Comment: What version of Asp.Net are you using? If it is 4.0 then you can change the ClientIdMode to static. check http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can still match your check boxes even if the `class` attribute is applied to their parent `<span>` elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sourceCheckBoxClass input:checkbox").click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {  // or $(this).is(":checked")
            $(".targetCheckBoxClass input:checkbox").attr("checked", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With ASP.NET you can control the ClientId of the form controls. You have the use the Clientid property as I remember.

More info at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Category_ctl00_ProductBusinessLine_chkEL_157').click(function() {

     if (this.checked) {
         var pl = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Category_ctl00_ProductBusinessLine_chkPL_313 :checkbox')


         pl.attr("checked", true);
     } 


         })
     }); 
</script>
```

Is that what you're looking for ? oh and looks like you're using ids, not classes in your selectors

Answer (score 0):

if you write your javascript code on the page, then you can determine real id dynamically:

```
$('#<$=chkEL_157.ClientID%>').click(function() {
  ...
});
```

or find element by a part of id:

```
$(':checkbox[id$="_chkEL_157"]').click(function() {
  ...
});
```

but in this case you must assure that there is no other element that contains similar id. Otherwise you must specify context where you want to find element, like this:

```
$(':checkbox[id$="_chkEL_157"]', $("#checkbox-context-element")).click(function() {
  ...
});
```